# How to use allocate java object in C memory?

Tags: java, c, memory, share

My question is that I want to share C memory with java, so I want to allocate `bytebuffer` object in C memory, in this way I will with zeroCopy between JAVA with C code. But I only find

`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(directBufferSize);`

I know this method will allocate `ByteBuffer` in C memory, but I want to control this memory by myself, it allocates this memory with my defined API.

Comment: The only thing I could find that might be helpful is this link: http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/memory_management.shtml

Comment: 2. The only slight exception in Java is that using the Java Native Interface (JNI), it possible to wrap a direct ByteBuffer around a block of memory allocated from native code (whose address is thus known). But the memory address still isn't exposed at the Java level, and from Java, the memory must still be accessed via that ByteBuffer object.

Comment: Yes, above describe is I need.but how to? any example?